# Set Character Encoding Read Multiple Character Sets In Cygwin Shell

Tags: linux, bash, encoding, character-encoding, cygwin

I have a file that contains various languages, including ASCII and native characters. I would like my shell to be able to process any language - English, Arabic, Chinese, Japanese, etc.

I read the cygwin page on 'Internationalization' and the list of supported character sets (below). Also, I have read the documentation on weird characters: https://cygwin.com/faq-nochunks.html#faq.using.weirdchars

```
    Charset               Codepage
-------------------   -------------------------------------------
ASCII                 20127 (US_ASCII)

CP437                   437 (OEM United States)
CP720                   720 (DOS Arabic)
CP737                   737 (OEM Greek)
CP775                   775 (OEM Baltic)
CP850                   850 (OEM Latin 1, Western European)
CP852                   852 (OEM Latin 2, Central European)
CP855                   855 (OEM Cyrillic)
CP857                   857 (OEM Turkish)
CP858                   858 (OEM Latin 1 + Euro Symbol)
CP862                   862 (OEM Hebrew)
CP866                   866 (OEM Russian)
CP874                   874 (ANSI/OEM Thai)
CP932           932 (Shift_JIS, not exactly identical to SJIS)
CP1125                 1125 (OEM Ukraine)
CP1250                 1250 (ANSI Central European)
CP1251                 1251 (ANSI Cyrillic)
CP1252                 1252 (ANSI Latin 1, Western European)
CP1253                 1253 (ANSI Greek)
CP1254                 1254 (ANSI Turkish)
CP1255                 1255 (ANSI Hebrew)
CP1256                 1256 (ANSI Arabic)
CP1257                 1257 (ANSI Baltic)
CP1258                 1258 (ANSI/OEM Vietnamese)

ISO-8859-1            28591 (ISO-8859-1)
ISO-8859-2            28592 (ISO-8859-2)
ISO-8859-3            28593 (ISO-8859-3)
ISO-8859-4            28594 (ISO-8859-4)
ISO-8859-5            28595 (ISO-8859-5)
ISO-8859-6            28596 (ISO-8859-6)
ISO-8859-7            28597 (ISO-8859-7)
ISO-8859-8            28598 (ISO-8859-8)
ISO-8859-9            28599 (ISO-8859-9)
ISO-8859-10             -   (not available)
ISO-8859-11             -   (not available)
ISO-8859-13           28603 (ISO-8859-13)
ISO-8859-14             -   (not available)
ISO-8859-15           28605 (ISO-8859-15)
ISO-8859-16             -   (not available)

Big5                    950 (ANSI/OEM Traditional Chinese)
EUCCN or euc-CN         936 (ANSI/OEM Simplified Chinese)
EUCJP or euc-JP       20932 (EUC Japanese)
EUCKR or euc-KR         949 (EUC Korean)
GB2312                  936 (ANSI/OEM Simplified Chinese)
GBK                     936 (ANSI/OEM Simplified Chinese)
GEORGIAN-PS             -   (not available)
KOI8-R                20866 (KOI8-R Russian Cyrillic)
KOI8-U                21866 (KOI8-U Ukrainian Cyrillic)
PT154                   -   (not available)
SJIS                    -   (not available, almost, but not exactly CP932)
TIS620 or TIS-620       874 (ANSI/OEM Thai)

UTF-8 or utf8         65001 (UTF-8)
```

My main question: is it possible to have cygwin shell read multiple languages at once? I haven't really been able to find much on this. Any direction is highly appreciated.

Comment: by default Cygwin use the UTF-8 as codification. You can convert any code page to another using iconv. See `man iconv` for details

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean?

With a recent Cygwin in a modern Windows (Windows 10), I can have Cygwin display all sorts of characters. For example

```
$ env LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8 cp --help
$ env LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8 cp --help
$ env LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8 cp --help
```

will display Russian, Chinese, Japanese text, and so on.

And if this did not work, you can also do it in Windows Powershell, albeit with an extra `iconv` step for postprocessing the output:

```
PS C:\cygwin\bin> .\env.exe LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8 .\cp.exe --help | .\iconv.exe -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16
```